# Reading Multipart Data from Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

We have a requirement of sending the jpeg files of a given directory to a Xamarin App.

Following is the code in the Web API.

```
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadMutipleFiles()
{
    name = "DirectoryName";
    var content = new MultipartContent();
    var ids = new List<int> { 1,2};

    var objectContent = new ObjectContent<List<int>>(ids, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    content.Add(objectContent);

    var file1Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"D:\Photos\" + name+"\\"+ "BL1408037_20191031124058_0.jpg", FileMode.Open));
    file1Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
    content.Add(file1Content);

    var file2Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"D:\Photos\" + name + "\\" + "BL1408037_20191031124058_1.jpg", FileMode.Open));
    file2Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
    content.Add(file2Content);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = content;
    return response;
}
```

Can some one help out with how to read from Xamarin app? Thanks in advance

Comment: According to your description, you have used web api to download jpeg in dictionary, now you want to pass these data for Xamarin app?

Comment: Yes, we do receive data in the Xamarin code from the mentioned code in API, but we cannot generate two images out of it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you make a. request to your endpoint, are you getting a correct response?

Comment: That is one of the issues too. I get a chunk of data when I access the endpoint from Postman or a browser. In size it is equivalent to the total of both the images. But I still could figure out a way generate two images from the sent data chunk.

Comment: Do you explicitly need to pass the data as Multipart Data?

Comment: In this scenario we are required to. Instead of sending URLs, is there any other way to send images to xamarin?

Comment: You could refer to: [Display image in Xamarin Forms app sourced from RESTful service](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69397/display-image-in-xamarin-forms-app-sourced-from-post-method-on-restful-service)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I was able to use to send an image as a multi part data file! I just took the byte array given to me by the Xamarin Essentials image picker and passed it into this function:

```
    public async Task SubmitImage(byte[] image, string imageName)
    {
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
        string url = $"..."; // URL goes here

        var token = Preferences.Get("AccessToken", "");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(image);

        var content = new StreamContent(stream);

        //Without a name we can't actually put the file in IFormFile. We need the equivalent
        //"name" value to be "file" (used if you upload via an <input> tag). We could call it
        //anything but file is simple
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
          FileName = imageName,
          Name = "file"
        };
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartContent.Add(content);

        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, multipartContent);
      }
    }
```

You can test this using a console application as well and just send over a picture from your computer, instead of doing this through the app